# Using binding generator to binding a subclass of cocos2d node

Tags: cocos2d-x

Binding generator is really very important to cocos2d-x jsb users.
However there is very little information to tell me how to use it.
I read the tutorial at http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/wiki/How_to_bind_C++_to_Javascript
And I can generate some simple classes. But simple classes is not that useful when facing a real project.

**I wrote a subclass of CCNode called RectClip. And I still have no idea how to generate the binding code using generator. When I simply place the samples, the generator gives me the error: can't open cocos2d.h.**

So how can I actually get this work done? I think the key is how to configure the .ini file.
But I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a configuration used by cocos2d-x at: cocos2d-x source/tools/tojs
I put my class files under cocos2d-x folders and added the class name into this configuration. it works.